# let webpack output individual compiled files besides bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-plugin

I'm using the webpack loader `ts-loader` to compile typescript sourcefiles into a javascript bundle. Now I would like the individualy compiled javascript files also to be saved, as well as the bundle! I'm familliar with writing a very simple webpack plugin, but I'm not sure as to how to go about implementing this. That is: I don't know which events triggered by webpack to listen to and where to find the relevant data. Any help?

Comment: You can't use individual webpack compiled files. It might break with `Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_require__ is not defined`

Comment: But I asume ts-loader compiles ts to js with the typescript compiler first before webpack changes anything in the code like requires right? I just want those separate js files

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, you can't use webpack compiled individual files. It might break with `Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_require__ is not defined`.

It's better write your own `loader` or ask the `ts-loader` to provide the option to retain the transpiled source.

Or i have written a [loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scatter-loader) which can save the typescript compiled files as individual files.

you can use this loader second loader or post-loader as shown below

as a second loader:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.ts?$/,
      loaders: ['scatter-loader', 'ts-loader']
    }]
}
```

or as a post-loader

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.ts?$/,
      loaders: ['ts-loader']
    }],
    postLoader: [{
      test: /\.ts?$/,
      loaders: ['scatter-loader']
    }]
}
```

**Note:** `scatter-loader` work is in progress.

Comment: Ah cool you actually already wrote a loader for this, Will check this out!